# подсветка кнопки в xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, дизайн

Как сделать такой же эффект на скрине ниже? У меня прописан tab bar, и нужно,чтобы при наведении на кнопку было нижнее подчеркивание.Какие свойства использовать?Заранее спасибо.

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не думаю что это конфигурируется свойствами, но написать такое в нуля в вас займет 2 минуты

Answer (score 1):

Может по синтаксису не совпадет с вашим, но идея надеюсь понятна.

```
@IBOutlet weak var view1 : UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2 : UIView!

@IBAction func allTextAction(sender: UIButton) {
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}

@IBAction func myTextAction(sender: UIButton) {
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ сделать то, что вы хотите, на мой взгляд такой:

Рисуете в любом графическом редакторе эти синие/серые линии и сохраняете как картинку в ресурсы проекта (лучше в формате png, чтоб помимо линий остальной холст был прозрачный). Затем в attributes inspector у tab bar item подставляете две картинки в свойства 'Image' & 'Selected image'. Получится например текст "Все записи" поверх вашей картинки. Все.

Можете еще поменять цвет шрифта у выбранной item в AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        return true
    }
```